# Can't make rewrite rule to work properly

Tags: .htaccess

I have a subdomain like `sub.domain.com` and my site is on a folder `sub.domain.com/folder`

I tried a hundred solutions and none worked properly. Basically what i want is to rewrite  `sub.domain.com/folder/page.php?page=home` with `sub.domain.com/folder/home`.

Can anyone help me? Can't seem to make it work with subdomain and folder too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in your web document root folder (often `public_html` or `htdocs`):

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub.domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?page=($1) [L]
```

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for `.htaccess` files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is even installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for `.htaccess` files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Still not working, 
mod_rewrite is loaded according to phpinfo(), 
AllowOverride All for the entire web directory. **Isn't there a way to do this with plain php?**

Comment: At this stage, you'll have to describe what you mean by not working. What do you do, and what happens. Also, are you able to confirm that mod-rewrite is installed.